# Non-zero ideal in algebraic integers generated by two elements

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I've been doing past questions for my exams next week and would like to check an answer:

> Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of the algebraic integers and let $0\neq a \in I$. Show that $\exists b \in I$ such that $I = (a,b)$.

I am allowed to assume that for non-zero ideals $I$ and $J$ $\exists$ an ideal $I'$ such that $II'$ is principal and $I', J$ are coprime.

My proof:

Let $J = (a)$ and so $\exists I'$ as above, so $II'=(b)$ for some $b \in I$ and $I'+J=A$ (where I have denoted the algebraic integers by $A$). Then $$I(I'+J)=I$$ and so $$I\subseteq II'+I(a)=(b)+I(a) \subseteq (a)+(b)=(a,b)$$ with the inverse inclusion being trivial. How does this look? I'm particularly lacking confidence with some of the inclusions (ideal multiplication distributivity etc).